# Netsuite CASE WHEN expression in custom search is returning "invalid expression"

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am new to writing CASE expressions in NetSuite. I have inserted the following expression in a formula field of a custom search.

```
CASE WHEN {item.custitem_custid}=05 OR {item.custitem_custid}=12 THEN
     ({item.custitem_margin}/2) 
ELSE 
     ({item.custitem_margin}/3)
END
```

and getting "invalid expression as a result. I am attempting to divide the margin field value by 2 if the WHEN case is true and divide by 3 if not true. Anybody have any idea as to what is wrong with my formula?

Comment: Your syntax looks OK to me. What record type are you searching? My thought is that the join isn't working correctly.

As a sidenote, when using division in formulas, NetSuite recommends you use `X / nullif(Y, 0)` instead of just `X / Y` in order to avoid dividing by zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add parentheses:

```
CASE WHEN ({item.custitem_custid}=05 OR {item.custitem_custid}=12) THEN
     ({item.custitem_margin}/2) 
ELSE 
     ({item.custitem_margin}/3)
END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with egrubaugh360 that the syntax is fine and likely the joins are not working correctly.  In your forumula, just double-check the "item." portion and see what you can do.

I also agree with the NVL() recommendation, but I can also see that your denominator is 2 and 3, respectively, therefore the NVL() function won't do anything to help.  PLEASE DO USE NVL() every time your denominator is an unknown value, such as from a field on your record/transaction.